# Add a custom button to UINavigationController subclass

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to customize the NavigationBar by subclassing the navigation controller.  For some reason I can't get the custom button to show up.  My setup is pretty straight forward  I have a ViewController which is embedded into a Navigation Controller which uses my custom subclass **NavController**:

```
@interface NavController ()

@end

@implementation NavController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *wlImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wl-icon.png"];

    UIButton *wlButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [wlButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, wlImage.size.width, wlImage.size.height)];
    [wlButton setBackgroundImage:wlImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *wlButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:wlButton];
    wlButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = wlButtonItem;
    self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

@end
```

When I try to test the app the only customization that appears to work is the tint. The button won't appear.

[image]

I am wondering if it has something to do with the Navigation Item.

Could it be that my Initial View Controller is overriding the Navigation Item within it's own default setup?

Comment: Your theory sounds promising.  Have you tried adding a different button in your initial view controller to test it?

Comment: Yeah, I can add buttons in the initial view controller just fine.  I just wanted to have a default view that would be setup in the subclass because the button that I want to add will be visible in all view controllers of my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the nav controller has a `navigationItem`, it's never actually used. You should be overriding the nav controller methods to push view controllers (or using the delegate methods) to instead modify the `navigationItem` of each new view controller pushed.

Comment: So I would set UINavigationItem property for each of my view controllers that would most likely be passed between different view controllers via a prepareForSegue method, right?  How would I do it with the delegate methods?

Comment: You can use the `– navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` delegate method to get a view controller and set its `navigationItem`.   Otherwise, you'll need to override both `– pushViewController:animated:` and `– popToViewController:animated:`.

Comment: Probably just edit the buttons on the navigation item rather than setting it.