# xcode custom UINavigationCotroller doesn't response to changes

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a story board with a NavigationController which implement my own NavigationViewController.

This is the setting code i use inside the NavigationViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNavigationStyle];
}

- (void) setNavigationStyle
{
    self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:245 green:246 blue:247 alpha:1];
    self.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    self.title = @"test";
    UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[shareItem, cameraItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
}
```

The backgroundColor settings works, and the navigation controller background colour is changed.
But when trying to add buttons or titles it just doesn't effect the navigation bar.

What am I doing wrong ?

UPDATE:
I have implemented UiNavigtaionControlerDelegate:

```
- (void) setNavigationStyle: (UINavigationController *)navigationController
{
    navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:245 green:246 blue:247 alpha:1];
    navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[shareItem, cameraItem];
    navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self setNavigationStyle:navigationController];
}
```

still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to similar question answer ([Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888648/add-a-cutom-button-to-uinavigationcontroller-subclass))

> While the nav controller has a navigationItem, it's never actually
>   used. You should be overriding the nav controller methods to push view
>   controllers (or using the delegate methods) to instead modify the
>   navigationItem of each new view controller pushed.

Implement the UINavigationControllerDelegate and navigationController:willShowViewController:animated method, and then change the navigationItem property.

Comment: ok but after implementing the delegation, where should i register that my object is the delegation object? meaning, how to notify the system that it should use my delegation ?

Comment: ok found the delegate property and set it to self.
look at my edited question.. it still doesn't work

Comment: try to set it thru viewController directly. like viewController.navigationItem.blabla = bla;

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Create an outlet to navigationbar and navigationitem and remove title,buttons,color etc..in IB

```
 - (void) setNavigationStyle
{
    self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:245 green:246 blue:247 alpha:1];
    self.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"test";
    UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[shareItem, cameraItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
}
```